# How can i configure ssl connexion in shibboleth idp?

Tags: ssl, shibboleth

I installed shibboleth idp and i configured server.xml connector port 8443 to use idp.jsk for ssl connetion. When i navigated to http://localhost:8080/idp/profile/Status, page appears with "ok" , but when i navigate to https://localhost:8443/idp/status, page appears with "SSL connection error"

What can i do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Is your web server set up to handle SSL? You need to provide details of your config setup

Comment: no, have you any tuto about how can i do it ?

Comment: i generate a certificate and i add it in server.xml but don't work

Comment: What is your setup? Is this on a linux box with apache/tomcat?